# Using SignalR HubContext in ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm starting to use SignalR in my ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET 7.

Currently, the clients are not receiving the message pushed by SignalR but I'm not receiving any errors either. Clients just don't receive anything. As I troubleshoot this, I want to make sure I'm using `IHubContext` correctly.

I understand that I can use the SignalR `IHubContext` in my controllers and be able to access my methods that are in the hub and I'm doing that using the code below. My question is about making sure the `IHubContext` is injected properly and available in my controllers.

Currently, all I do in my `Program.cs` are as follows -- see below. Is there anything else I need to do to make sure `IHubContext` is available in my controllers?

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseSignalRQueryStringAuth();

app.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub");
```

And I use the `IHubContext` as follows in my controller:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IHubContext<MySignalRHub> _myHub;

   public MyController(IHubContext<MySignalRHub> myHub)
   {
       _myHub = myHub;
   }

   [HttpPost("dosomething")]
   public async Task<IActionResult>DoSomething()
   {
       // Do something here
       // Then notify connected clients using SignalR
       await _myHub.SomeMethod("Something new happened!");
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use the IHubContext to invoke methods on the client, not on the Hub. Maybe that's the issue you're running into? Also, turn on client side logging to see if there are any errorrs?

Comment: Maybe try this `await _myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Something");`

Comment: @davidfowl The docs show how to use `IHubContext` in a `Controller` which is exactly what I'm doing. I know you're one of the original architects of SignalR so I'm misunderstanding either what you're saying or the docs. To clarify, I have a `Hub` and a `Controller` in my backend and when something happens, I'm trying to use `IHubContext` in my `Controller` to send a message to connected clients. Is this not correct? Here's the doc I was following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0#inject-an-instance-of-ihubcontext-in-a-controller

Comment: All I am saying is that the method you are calling is on the "Client", not the "Server" side.

Comment: @davidfowl You're right. The issue was because of how I was using `IHubContext`. It's working now. Thanks.